# How do I make Raspberry Pi OS Lite log in automatically on boot and just loop a FLAC/WAV/MP3 file over and over?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have downloaded Raspberry Pi OS Lite and "burned" it onto the flash card and it's in my RPI (v1). I have also put a FLAC (or OGG, or MP3) sound file onto it.

It's not going to have any keyboard/mouse/monitor/network access. Its *sole* purpose is to perpetually loop the same sound file (10 hours recorded rain), outputting it to the loudspeakers attached to the RPI, as soon as it gets power.

If I cut the power at any point, I need it to start back up again the next time I plug it in, and not require me to do any kind of "fiddling about" because it was "unexpectedly shut down" or anything like that.

It's a poor man's "white noise generator" to help me sleep with noisy neighbours. Since I have the RPI and the loudspeakers, I thought this would be more than doable, and almost insultingly "low-tech" for such a capable electronic device.

What exact steps do I need to take to make it so that it does this? I assume that I have to make some kind of edit on the flash card to make it not ask for username/password on boot, and another edit to make it actually play the sound file (and loop it) when it has started up?

Comment: May I suggest an extremely high-tech device called an "ear plug".  They're so advanced they use absolutely no electricity at all.   You can get them as cheap, disposable foam plugs or more modern washable/re-usable silicone plugs.   Both versions are very effective, I find they even work in extremely noisy environments like the "80+ decibels of hell" of a hospital ward.

Comment: Please tell us what program you use to play your sound files, and confirm that you can do this from the command line. After that, I think I'd try `cron` first a `@reboot` schedule.

Comment: @cas I have tried ear plugs. They are horrific. Total silence and hearing your own heartbeat is *not* pleasant, and they physically feel terrible on top of that. I can't breathe with them in my ears.

Comment: @Seamus I asked how to do it. I'm not currently using anything.

Comment: Oh, my apologies - I thought you had actually tried some things.

Comment: @Seamus I wouldn't know what things to try. I'm wondering how to do them.

Answer (score 0):

Playing mp3 from command line:

If you have vlc installed (which if I remember well is included with Raspberry Pi OS) it comes with a command line interface nvlc.

You could play a file in loop with:

```
nvlc -L your.mp3
```

To make this happen every time you turn on your RPI you can add a line like this to your crontab

```
@reboot nvlc -L /path/to/your.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look at [Musikcube](https://github.com/clangen/musikcube/wiki/raspberry-pi), a commandline player designed for headless systems such as rasberry pi. More details on their [website](https://musikcube.com/)